# Connect to ravendb linux client?

Tags: ravendb

Is there any way to browse ravendb in linux, other than web interface based on silverlight?

Unfortuantely i have some problems installing silverlight for firefox or chromium.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically access [the HTTP/REST API](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api) from any platform, but the management UI is only available in Silverlight.

Comment: @AyendeRahien i hope you inform me here? :D